# getting data from internal storage

Tags: android, memory, storage, internal

I'd like to read all files located in internal storage and filter them to find those *.mp3 ones. With external storage I could just use:

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

to get the path, but I cannot find the way to do it for internal memory (for instance to get to Music folder of the phone). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you do get the internal storage with that. sounds weird but this is the external storage. it's a bit more complicated to read the sd card

Comment: @user2957782 am I? Cause I've got some songs in my phone and the app can't see them (in `Music` folder). In the emulator they are seen in the `sdCard` after I pushed them there.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: thanks, in my case  `final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Music").getPath();` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of getFilesDir() method?

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Context.getFilesDir()` method to get the path to the internal storage.

Like : `File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + name);`